# How to write a program that takes data such as first and last name, etc., using an array for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to create variables that do not exist when we define an empty array and put them inside the array

I want to put this code let {}=student is equal to this instead of the array, in that case how should I define the variable

```
let studentsMembers = parseInt(prompt('Members of students: ')),
    studentsList = [];

for (let index = 0; index < studentsMembers; index++) {
    let student = {};

    student.firstName = prompt(`Enter the name of student #${index + 1}:`);
    student.lastName = prompt(`Enter last name of student ${student.firstName}:`);
    student.age = Number(prompt(`How old is ${student.firstName}?`));

    while (true) {
        student.grade = Number(prompt(`What grade does ${student.firstName} have?`));
        if (student.grade >= 0 && student.grade <= 20) break;
    }

    while (true) {
        student.studentID = prompt(`Enter student ID (10 digits) for student ${student.firstName}:`);
        if (student.studentID.length === 10) break;
    }

    while (true) {
        student.phoneNumber = prompt(`Enter phone number (11 digits) for student ${student.firstName}:`);
        if (student.phoneNumber.length === 11) break;
    }

    studentsList.push(student);
}

console.log("Student Details:");
console.log("==================================================================================");

for (let index = 0; index < studentsMembers; index++) {
    let student = studentsList[index];
    console.log(`${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}\t Age: ${student.age}\t Grade: ${student.grade}\t ID: ${student.studentID}\t Phone: ${student.phoneNumber}`);
}

console.log("==================================================================================");

let passCounter = 0,
    FailedCounter = 0;

for (let index = 0; index < studentsMembers; index++) {
    if (studentsList[index].grade >= 10) {
        console.log(`Student Name: ${studentsList[index].firstName} Status: Passed`);
        passCounter++;
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Student Name: ${studentsList[index].firstName} Status: Failed`);
        FailedCounter++;
    }
}

console.log(`Total members: ${studentsMembers}\nPassed students: ${passCounter} \nFailed students: ${FailedCounter}`);
```

Comment: What does "let {}=student is equal to this instead of the array" mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including what specifically isn't working as expected in the code shown and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.